# Trouble isolating $x$ in $100(35 + x) = 32(90 + x)$, prior to solving the equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is probably a basic question for this forum, but I'm trying to rewrite an equation so that it can be solved with an excel formula for something at work.

The equation looks like this when plugging in example numbers:

$$100(35 + x) = 32(90 + x)$$

I can solve the above by hand, but I haven't been to figure out if it's possible to isolate x **before** solving. That way I could write an excel formula to solve for x. Any tips?? Thanks so much.

Comment: $3500+100x=2880+32x$ i.e. $68x=-620$ i.e. $x=-\frac{68}{620}$. Basically, multiply the terms in the brackets using distributivity, then move everything that has $x$ to one side and everything else to the other side, then divide by the factor multiplying $x$ to get $x$ alone.

Comment: Or, if your equation is (more generally) $A(B+x)=C(D+x)$ then $AB+Ax=CD+Cx$ i.e. $AB-CD=(C-A)x$ i.e. $x=\frac{C-A}{AB-CD}$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thank you thank you! I was getting to that first part of solving for x, but yes, I needed that second more general piece of x = c-a/ab-cd. That got me where I needed to be for an excel formula and saved me a few hours of doing this by hand. Thanks so much!